# how to use sed or awk to change from line delimiter to CSV

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Is it possible to have the the following data set:

```
| asn-query: 
| BGP: 8.8.8.0/24 | Country: US
|   Origin AS: 15169 - GOOGLE - Google Inc., US
|    Peer AS: 1103 1239 2381 3257 6453
```

to be converted into this structure, using sed\awk

```
asn-query, BGP: 8.8.8.0/24,  Country: US, Origin AS: 15169 - GOOGLE - Google Inc., US, Peer AS: 1103 1239 2381 3257 6453
```

Comment: Are there pipe symbols at start of each line?

Comment: Yes it is certainly possible... it looks like you're just trying to outsource the work to someone else.

Comment: the 3 hours i've invested in trying to get this to work doesn't feel like outsource the work to someone else, i just learned to quit and ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file have multiple blocks of the above text, for example, if your file contains:

```
| asn-query: 
| BGP: 8.8.8.0/24 | Country: US
|   Origin AS: 15169 - GOOGLE - Google Inc., US
|    Peer AS: 1103 1239 2381 3257 6453
| asn-query: 
| BGP: 2.2.2.0/24 | Country: XX
|   Origin AS: 11111 - XXXXX - YYYYY Inc., US
|    Peer AS: 1212 1313 1414 1515 1616
```

you could use the `paste` utility to join every 4 lines to one line, e.g.

```
paste - - - - < the_above_file.txt
```

will produce two lines:

```
| asn-query:    | BGP: 8.8.8.0/24 | Country: US |   Origin AS: 15169 - GOOGLE - Google Inc., US |    Peer AS: 1103 1239 2381 3257 6453
| asn-query:    | BGP: 2.2.2.0/24 | Country: XX |   Origin AS: 11111 - XXXXX - YYYYY Inc., US   |    Peer AS: 1212 1313 1414 1515 1616
```

and could modify each line as you wish, for example:

```
paste  - - - - < asn.txt | sed 's/\|[[:blank:]]*//;s/://;s/[[:blank:]]*\|[[:blank:]]*/,/g'
```

will produce:

```
asn-query,BGP: 8.8.8.0/24,Country: US,Origin AS: 15169 - GOOGLE - Google Inc., US,Peer AS: 1103 1239 2381 3257 6453
asn-query,BGP: 2.2.2.0/24,Country: XX,Origin AS: 11111 - XXXXX - YYYYY Inc., US,Peer AS: 1212 1313 1414 1515 1616
```

same using perl (and explained)

```
paste  - - - - < asn  |  perl -plE 's/\|\s*//; s/://; s/\s*\|\s*/,/g'
                                    ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                       ^         ^        ^
replace the 1st |+spaces with nothing--+         |        |
                                                 |        |
replace the 1st : with nothing ------------------+        |
                                                          |
replace all spaces + | + spaces with , -------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n//g' -e 's/|[[:blank:]]//g' file
```

For explanation, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/3744681).

Or you can simplify it (a lot) using `tr`:

```
sed -e 's/|[[:blank:]]//g' file |tr -d '\n'
```

In this second method, you won't be able to use seds' `-i` flag to perform in-place edit. You can use this:

```
echo "$(sed -e 's/|[[:blank:]]//g' file |tr -d '\n')" > file
```

as an alternative of in-place edit, or use a different file:

```
sed -e 's/|[[:blank:]]//g' file |tr -d '\n' > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat file | xargs echo -n | sed -e 's/ |/,/g' -e 's/:,/,/g' -e 's/| //g'`

Comment: cat file | xargs -L | sed ' s/|/,/g' |sed 's/,//'  

This can be done

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= -F'\\s*\\|\\s*' -v OFS=', ' '{sub(FS,"");$1=$1}1' file
asn-query:, BGP: 8.8.8.0/24, Country: US, Origin AS: 15169 - GOOGLE - Google Inc., US, Peer AS: 1103 1239 2381 3257 6453
```

The above is gawk-specific due to multi-char RS and is explained by reading the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gnu awk command:

```
awk -v RS='(: *)?\n*\\|[[:blank:]]*' -v ORS=', ' 'NR>1 && RT; END{printf "%s", $0}' file

asn-query, BGP: 8.8.8.0/24 , Country: US, Origin AS: 15169 - GOOGLE - Google Inc., US, Peer AS: 1103 1239 2381 3257 6453
```